# "On the one hand side"

Tags: phrase-usage

At my (large, multinational, Germany-headquartered) employer, I frequently hear "on the one hand side... on the other hand side" by non-native speakers. This always sets my teeth on edge. However, I have heard it often enough coming from many different people that I'm getting unsure of my intuition. Then again, it could just be incorrect usage spreading from non-native speaker to non-native speaker.

Is "on the one hand side" accepted usage, or is my hunch correct that it isn't?

[This question is related.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73179/on-the-one-other-hand-vs-on-the-one-other-side)

Comment: I'm sure you know that, but just for the sake of completeness: In Germany they literally say "on the one side...on the other side"

Comment: I've certainly never heard or seen it anywhere, and Google hits all seem to be from (and many of them also about) Germlish specifically, so I'd say it's probably a feature limited mostly to non-native speakers who have German as their first language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In places like NYC, where people from almost any country on the planet can find a neighborhood where their native language is spoken, it's common to hear "slightly-off idioms" that are characteristic among those who speak the same native tongue.

I suspect that they adapt what they hear from native speakers, so that it makes sense in the syntax of their own languages.

Sometimes, they just like the way it sounds - for instance: My grandparent's generation came from Italy to NYC.  It was common to hear the phrase, "Bumper-to-bumper traffic," on the radio. Grandma and Grandpa (and their "paesans") used to say, "If we go to the beach, we gotta leave extra time 'cause you got the "bom-bidi-bom" out there." Among Italians in the area, "bom-bidi-bom" became synonymous with "heavy traffic.

I think your following assessment is correct:
"...incorrect usage spreading from non-native speaker to non-native speaker."

Comment: Likewise in Italian the equivalent discourse marker is: ["on the one side.... and on the other (side)"](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/da%20un%20lato%E2%80%A6%20dall%27altro%E2%80%A6) I also think it's a type of malapropism mixing "on the one hand" and the expressions "right/left hand side"

Answer (score -1):

your hunch is correct sir: In the other one hand side is a wrong translation---please see:

http://www.linguee.com/english-german/translation/on+the+one+hand+side.html